# Flutter : How to pass the same data between two widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, flutter-widget

I was building an app that shows the list of the teams by their name on search. Now I want to navigate to the new screen and show the detail information about the team when clicked on the list items.

Here is the block of code for the List view :

```
import 'package:fetchuser/team_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TeamList extends StatefulWidget {
  String category;

  TeamList({this.category});

  _TeamListState createState() {
    return _TeamListState(category: category);
  }
}

class _TeamListState extends State<TeamList> {
  String category;

  _TeamListState({this.category});

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchTeams() async {
    var result;
    try {
      result = await http.get(
          "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php?t=${widget.category}");
      return json.decode(result.body)['teams'];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  String _teamName(dynamic user) {
    return user['strTeam'];
  }

  String _location(dynamic user) {
    return user['strCountry'];
  }

  String _description(dynamic user){
    return user['strStadiumDescription'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: fetchTeams(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("No Teams found"),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {

                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => TeamDetails(teamList: TeamList(category: category,),)));
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 30,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    snapshot.data[index]['strTeamBadge'])),
                            title: Text(_teamName(snapshot.data[index])),
                            subtitle: Text(_location(snapshot.data[index])),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error),
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the block of code for the description page :

```
import 'package:fetchuser/team_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TeamDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final TeamList teamList;

  const TeamDetails({ this.teamList});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,color: Colors.black,),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),

      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text(_description(snapshot.data[index]['strStadiumDescription'])),
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

I have just started working with flutter what should I do to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data correctly but to get the data from the widget (TeamDetails) you have to get by using this code:

```
widget.teamlist
```

You can call widget.teamlist to get the data and use it anywhere inside the widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can pass `snapshot.data[index]` and receive with `Map<String, dynamic>` 
code snippet

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => TeamDetails(
                        teamList: snapshot.data[index],
                      )));
...
class TeamDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> teamList;

...
 Text("${teamList['strStadiumDescription']}"),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TeamList extends StatefulWidget {
  String category;

  TeamList({this.category});
  @override
  _TeamListState createState() => _TeamListState();
}

class _TeamListState extends State<TeamList> {
  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchTeams() async {
    var result;
    try {
      result = await http.get(
          "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchteams.php?t=${widget.category}");
      return json.decode(result.body)['teams'];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  String _teamName(dynamic user) {
    return user['strTeam'];
  }

  String _location(dynamic user) {
    return user['strCountry'];
  }

  String _description(dynamic user) {
    return user['strStadiumDescription'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: fetchTeams(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("No Teams found"),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => TeamDetails(
                                    teamList: snapshot.data[index],
                                  )));
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 30,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    snapshot.data[index]['strTeamBadge'])),
                            title: Text(_teamName(snapshot.data[index])),
                            subtitle: Text(_location(snapshot.data[index])),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error),
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TeamDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> teamList;

  const TeamDetails({this.teamList});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("${teamList['strStadiumDescription']}"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: TeamList(
        category: "football",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```